# How to implement the sequential write operation in C?

Tags: c, file, io, fwrite

I have a set of data pages to be written in my storage device. I would like to write these N pages by using a sequential write strategy.

Please, assume that the pages are sequential (its RNN values are stored in an ordered array called *pages* with capacity equal to *npages* - the content of these pages are serialized in the *buf* array). However, my main doubt is how to do it in C.

Which form is the most correct?

Please note that I am using DIRECT I/O.

First form -> performing N consecutive writes

```
void disk_write(char *file, int *pages, uint8_t *buf, int npages) {
    int f;
    int real_size;
    int i;

    if ((f = open(file, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
        //error
    }

    if (lseek(f, pages[0] * page_size, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
        //error
    }

    for(i = 0; i < npages; i++) {
        if ((real_size = write(f, buf + i * page_size, page_size)) != page_size) {
            //(ERROR, "Sizes do not match in raw_write -> %d - %d", page_size, real_size);
        }
    }

    close(f);
}
```

Second form -> performing a big write as a unique (batch) operation

```
void disk_write(char *file, int *pages, uint8_t *buf, int npages) {
    int f;
    int real_size;
    int i;

    if ((f = open(file, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
        //error
    }

    if (lseek(f, pages[0] * page_size, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
        //error
    }

    if ((real_size = write(f, buf, page_size * npages)) != page_size * npages) {
        //(ERROR, "Sizes do not match in raw_write -> %d - %d", page_size * npages, real_size);
    }

    close(f);
}
```

Comment: If the data to be written are contiguous in memory, as you seem to be saying, then I'd be inclined to write them all as a single unit.  But it is not in any way *incorrect* to write each page separately.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, in my case the data to be written are contiguous in memory. If now I say to you that I am using a flash storage device (e.g., SSD)?

Comment: You can use [`pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) to replace `lseek()`/`write()` operations with a single system call.  If you're running on Linux, just be sure to read the "Bugs" section on the [Linux `pwrite()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html).

Comment: @AndersonCarniel, it makes no difference what the output device is.  Where a particular device has special needs, it is the responsibility of its *driver* to handle them.  You are clearly not writing a driver.  I would not expect the two variations you present to have different effects on the output device.

Comment: the call to `lseek()` is moving the logical file pointer to `pages * pageSize` down the file, This is probably NOT what you want.  Suggest removing the call(s) to `fseek()`

Comment: parameter and variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  suggest:  replace `file` with `filename`

Comment: exactly what is the parameter `int *pages` expected to be pointing toward?  Currently, it seems to be being used to cause a large 'gap' at the beginning of the output file.   If it is actually to cause a 'gap' at the beginning of the output file, then a much better name would be `gapSize` and since it is never written to, could be better passed as `int gapSize`  rather than a pointer to int.